# Construction of Lebesgue measure using two different approaches.

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm going to study in a possibly serious way the construction of Lebesgue measure.
What are the advantages/disadvantages of the following two approaches in order to build the Lebesgue measure?

1. Constructing Lebesgue measure using Carathéodory theorem and outer measure (see Folland);
2. Constructing Lebesgue measure through Riesz representation theorem (see Rudin).

**I have heard that the first one is more general and technically easy. Is it true?**

I have already studied in a soft way the construction of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, by defining Lebesgue measurable sets to be the ones that can be well approximated by open sets from the outside and by closed sets from the inside. **Is this the most direct way to proceed?  Again, which one of the previous two approaches is more similar to this last construction?**

Again, I'm also interested in Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure construction. **Maybe with the first approach (Carathéodory) I can obtain both Lebesgue and Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures at the same time?**

Thank you!

Comment: If you are going to study in a serious way the construction of Lebesgue measure, you must learn **both** ways. So the question is actually which one to study first.  **In general**, you should start by the approach "using Carathéodory theorem and outer measure"  first and then study the approach  "through Riesz representation theorem", unless you have a specific reason / motivation to do in the reversed order.